# Como recuperar todos os dados dentro da key no Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

Tenho essa estrutura no Firebase.
E preciso capturar todas as latitudes e longitudes que estão dentro de cada key, fiz um teste e está funcionando se eu por esses dados em uma pasta sem a key ela aparece o marcador no mapa sem problemas, mas apenas um, eu quero capturar e adicionar todos como marcadores no mapa, como posso fazer? com um for?

[image: firebase database]

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ref.child("uploads").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                double location_left = (dataSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class));
                double location_right = Double.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class));
                LatLng local = new LatLng(location_left, location_right);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(local).title("Novo Marcador"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(local, 18));
            } else {
                Log.i("MeuLOG", "erro na captura");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar seu problema faz o seguinte:

Faz a declaração em escopo global destas variáveis

```
private String nome;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
Marker marcador;
```

Depois é só fazer alteração em seu método.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ref.child("uploads").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

        for (DataSnapshot s : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

            nome = s.child("nome").getValue().toString();
            latitude = s.child("latitude").getValue().toString();
            longitude = s.child("longitude").getValue().toString();
            LatLng zoom = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(latitude), Double.valueOf(longitude));

            marcador = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(latitude), Double.valueOf(longitude)))
                            .title(nome));

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(zoom, 18));

            } 
        } else {
            Log.i("MeuLOG", "erro na captura");
        }

    }
}
```

Esta função além de percorrer cada `id` de sua base de dados contido em `upload` para coletar as `latitudes` e `longitudes`, também irá inserir no marcador seus `nomes` respectivos, caso tenha na base de dados.

Tenho projeto que trabalha com `mapas` e `Firebase`.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

ref.child("uploads").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                double location_left = postSnapshot.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
                // resto do codigo
            }
        } else {
            Log.i("MeuLOG", "erro na captura");
        }
    }
}
```

Um pouco sem tempo para explicar o que o código faz exatamente, mas, basicamente, ele percorre todo o seu node com a lógica que fora aplicada, utilizando um **for**. Utilizei o `addValueEventListener` para que você possa percorrer todos os itens ao invés de apenas um. Você recebe todo o node `uploads` e vai poder percorrer entre os dados dele.

Comment: IAMLuc, obrigado pela dica, mas para mim não funcionou, está dando erro null object reference nos dois gets, ele não está encontrando o objeto, o que está errado?  se for pelo meu código acima colocando a child em uma pasta exemplo que criei chamada "up" onde contem apenas 1 dado de latitude e longitude ele funciona, problema na key será?

Comment: Utilizando seu código e utilizando um Log.v("log",""+local); Ele captura todos os dados que tem latitude e longitude e imprimi para mim no logcat. Mas após abrir o mapa, onde deveria adicionar os marcadores no mapa, ele fecha o app e mostra no logcat isto>> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference

Comment: Onde você está colocando o código de adição de marcadores?

Comment: Acho que o correto seria abrir o mapa primeiro e depois pegar os dados no firebase para adicionar os marcadores no mapa.

Comment: O código de adição de marcadores está no código acima na pergunta, é só isso ali, tenho a classe ShowMap que contem o mapa onde ele localiza e aponta a minha localização atual e após isso o código acima onde ele busca no Firebase os dados e deveria adicionar os marcadores no mapa, mas não acaba fazendo, pergunto precisa de entidade get/set para efetuar esse procedimento, ou que está errado. E tenho no main um botão que faz intent para o mapa.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta assim:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Postagem.removeAll(Postagem);
            for (DataSnapshot single: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                if (single.exists()) {

                        double location_left = (single.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class));
                        double location_right = Double.valueOf(single.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class));
                        LatLng local = new LatLng(location_left, location_right);
                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(local).title("Novo Marcador"));
                        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(local, 18));
                } else {
                    Log.i("MeuLOG", "erro na captura");
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    ref.addValueEventListener(listener);
```